# passing data from custom adapter to another activity

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview which consist of items with prices. My listview also has a Delete button. I also have a textview at the bottom part of the layout which is not part of the listview and it shows the total amount. I can successfully remove the item from my listview. What I want is that when the item is removed, the total amount will also change.

Here is a part of my adapter where i must do some actions

```
 holder.del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          remove(getItem(position));
     }
});
```

and here is my Activity where my textview of amount is found.

```
public class Cart extends MainActivity {

TextView amount_total;
ListView cartList;
CartCustomAdapter cartCustomAdapter;
String name, price;
static ArrayList<Order> cartArray = new ArrayList<Order>();

static Double total_amount = 0.00d;
static Double temp = 0.00d;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

    amount_total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_tv);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    Button checkout =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.check_out);
    Button add_item = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_item);
        name = bundle.getString("i_name");
        price = bundle.getString("i_price");
        temp = Double.parseDouble(price);
        total_amount = (total_amount + temp);
        amount_total.setText("Php" + total_amount.toString());
    add_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Cart.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
    cartList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cart_list);

    cartCustomAdapter = new CartCustomAdapter(Cart.this,R.layout.list_cart,cartArray);
    cartList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    cartList.setAdapter(cartCustomAdapter);

    cartArray.add(new Order(name,price,"1"));

    cartCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

}
```

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your UI and adapter class code also?

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface with method like below to update text view in your activity :

```
updateDeletedItemCount();
```

and in this method take integer and increase its count like

```
deletedCount++;
```

and then update it on text view like this

```
tvDeletedCount.setText("Deleted Item Count : "+ deletedCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to do that:

```
//Add a method to your Cart
public void changeTotal(int totalPrice){
    if(textView != null) // set total price
}
// Call after remove an item in your listener:
if(getContext() instanceOf Cart){
    ((Cart)getContext()).changeTotal(newTotalPrice);
}
```

This is not the best way, but I think it's ok for now :)

Comment: this somehow worked but there is a bug. It does subtract and changes the total amount if i delete an item, but if i delete all the items the total amount goes back to the original. i'll try else condition if textview is null.

Comment: the bug or not is up to your total price calculating function.